# Google Fonts не отображаются на iOS-устройствах

Tags: html, css, ios, шрифты, google-fonts

Не отображаются Google Fonts на iOS-устройствах (на Android все отображается как надо).

[Ссылка на верстку](http://dev.difiz.com/smn)

Код:

```css
body {
  font: 400 1.11111111vw/1.59722222vw 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Say My Name</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Результат на любом iOS устройстве:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, вы кириллицу забыли подключить.

Comment: Ну работает же на десктопе.

Comment: Именно поэтому и написал комментарием а не ответом. Возможно у нас они в системе у всех есть)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы кириллицу забыли подключить.